# Envelope of a Sliding circle

Tags: geometry, envelope

"Find the envelope of the circle whose diameter is a line of constant length which slides between two fixed straight lines at right angles."

I could not figure out equation exactly, may be I don't even understand the problem.

Can anyone suggest the equation of the family?

Comment: Hint: What is the distance between the centers of family of circles and the intersection point of the two straight lines?

Comment: @achillehui Is it the radius?

Comment: yes, it equals to the radius of the circles and is a constant (half of the length of the constant line), this means....

Comment: @achillehui I didn't understand how the circle is sliding so that it's diameter remains constant.

Comment: Is it the circle that slides or its diameter? I would read that as letting the line segment side, then get the circle with that segment as diameter noting that the circle will intersect the lines not just touch them, then get the envelope of that.

Comment: The problem here is how to intepret "line of constant length which slides between two fixed straight lines at right angles." That is such a vague description that I can think of a large number of scenarios that would fit it, but give vastly different answers. Is there any other information available, like a graph? Without something more, any answer given would depend heavily on someone's choice of interpretation.

Comment: Exactly @PaulSinclair, That's the problem I am facing, unfortunately, nothing more is given.

Comment: @MvG I think your point of view, will actually work, Can you provide the equation of the family in that case?

Comment: MvG's interpretation is definitely the intent as far as it goes, but it doesn't address the ambiguity I was referring to. You need to ask your teacher or other resource to clarify. There are two scenarios that seem most likely to be the intent, but I cannot choose between them, and further, they both make significant assumptions. But I consider those assumptions are more likely to be something the problem writer would not bother to explain than other possibile interpretations.

Comment: The first scenario is that "at right angles" means "at right angles to the diameter", so the two lines are parallel, the diameter is perpendicular to them, and must remain so as it slides. The sliding consists of the diameter moves from having one endpoint on one of the lines to having the other endpoint on the other line. Contrary to MvG's description, the circle is never more than tangent to the lines in this case.

Comment: The second scenario is that the two "lines" are the start and ending positions of the diameter, and are at right angles to each other. Further, they share an endpoint with each other and with the diameter in all of its positions. The diameter "slides" by rotating about that endpoint from one position to the other. The first scenario gives you an envelope in logenze shape: a rectangle with two half-circles adjoin to opposite ends. The second scenario gives a quarter circle of twice the diameter with two half-circles adjoined to its edge radii.

Comment: thanks a lot @PaulSinclair This is actually a problem from a book, that's the only information I have that I have written. But I can confirm that the answer given in the book is "A circle centred at origin."

Comment: You are reading this book on your own, then, not for some class? But in any case, that answer does not fit either of my scenarios, and off the top of my head, I don't see an interpretation that leads to that answer (particularly since there was no "origin" specified in the problem) . I would write it off as just a really poorly written problem and move on, hoping the author does better in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses, actually I am teaching this topic, one of my students brought me this problem , initially I was also thinking that it is not well-posed.

Comment: What is title/author/publication of the book you are teaching from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the question as:

*Find the envelope of the semicircle whose diameter is a  ladder of length $2R$  sliding between a wall and floor.*

A steel semicircle is welded to its diameter which is the sliding ladder.

[image]

Inclination to floor/ horizontal is $\theta$. The locus of the ladder mid-point during sliding is a quarter of a circle.. which can be separately proved if needed.

$$ ( x- R\cos \theta)^2 + (y-R \sin \theta)^2=R^2 \tag1 $$

Partially differentiate  with respect to $\theta$ the parameter or angle which the ladder makes to  floor when sliding. The C-discriminant method is used:

$$2(x-R \cos\theta) \cdot R\sin\theta+ 2 (y-R\sin \theta) \cdot-R \cos\theta =0 \tag2$$

Simplifying

$$ \tan \theta =\frac{y}{x}\tag 3 $$

The above is suggestive of a circle envelope but is not yet conclusive..

Plug the above into 1) to eliminate $ \theta. $ The sliding semicircle envelope equation after simplification becomes:

$$ (x^2+y^2) \left( 1-\frac{R}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2  =R^2 \tag 4  $$

There is another envelope for the bottom side semicircle, which physically interferes with the wall..so not given now but can be included for a more complete answer.

A geometrical construction $R=1$ gives a sense that the envelope is a quarter of a circle. Still checking my work. Hope no errors in understanding the question, formulation or typing.

A rough sketched envelope:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As comments to your question discuss various alternatives, here is the way I read your problem: you have two infinite lines meeting at a right angle. Without loss of generality let's assume them to be the two coordinate axes. And you have a line of fixed length, whose one end point is on one of the lines and whose other end point is on the other of the lines. Let's assume that the length of this line is $2$, so that you get a circle of radius $1$ constructed over that line. Never mind that the circle itself intersects the two orthogonal lines; it's only the end points of the diameter which slide, not the circle itself.

[Thales's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) tells you that if you look at the triangle formed by the end points of the diameter and the point where the fixed lines intersect, that triangle is a right-angled triangle and therefore the point where the fixed lines intersect has to lie on the circle as well. So all the positions of the sliding circle can be characterized by the point of intersection (the origin in my above choice of lines) being a point on the circle.

What is the envelope of a circle of radius $1$ rotating around a point on its boundary? It's a circle of radius $2$. In the more general setup, you get a circle whose radius is equal to the diameter that slides, centered on the point where the two fixed lines intersect.

Things would be more complicated if you had rays instead of lines, i.e. if you were to restrict the sliding endpoints to not move beyond the point of intersection. But I see nothing in your problem statement to suggest that extra complexity.